# How to get rid of the Scrollbar on this page and keep it at FULL Width?

Tags: html, width, scrollbar

I am trying to get rid of the scrollbar on this page:  http://opportunityfinance.net/Test/2013conf/

The horizontal scrollbar seems to be there at all times no matter how wide the content is.  What is wrong here? Set the width to 100%, why do I see a scrollbar at the bottom of the page?

Please help... Thanks guys/gals :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove padding from `.footer` and your `<div>` that contains "sponsorship opportunities"

Answer (score 0):

Your footer has a padding (line #115 in index.css)  which is not zero. Thats why it makes the page wider than 100%. Change it to padding:0;

```
.footer {
 ...
 padding: 1.5em;
 ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I changed the footer to `padding: 0`, but scrollbar still exists at the bottom.

Comment: Its ok in opera and chrome here. Maybe you see a cached version? try to clean the browser cache (ctrl-F5 or shift-F5), or use another browser .